# No_SWT InputMethods Eclipse/Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, eclipse

After i've upgraded to ubuntu 12.04, eclipse doesn't show fonts properly and there are some problems with Auto Complete. New entry in the right click menu **"No_SWT InputMethods (no resource bundle)".** How i can restore my eclipse back ?

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Therefore VTC as `not reproducible`.